# FOS User Bundle + PHPCR-ODM = ? (Symfony CMF)

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

Public admin backends obviously need some authentication mechanism. With a standard Symfony2 edition there are Sonata Admin and FOS User Bundle used for this purpose.
But how about using FOS User Bundles within Sonata based on PHPCR-ODM with Symfony CMF? Is there kind of integration there? I haven't found any documenation on this.

Comment: Have a look at this gist here https://gist.github.com/dbu/7639476
Should still work fine ..

Comment: @0x7fffffff do you really want lukas to include 200 lines of code in his answer? And it would be much more user friendly if you told Lukas what was wrong with his answer and let him fix it before deleting it straight away.

Comment: It'd be best to provide some documentation like a recipe to cookbook for doing thing like this. I think there's no need to guess that people who are serious about using Symfony CMF would definetely need to have a user logging solution, as it's a very core feature to any CMS.